# Attribute sets based on user role

Tags: attribute-set, user-roles

I have been charged with customizing Magento 1.9.1 and my question seems complicated to me, but might not to a seasoned MageDev.

What I want to do is have an attribute set, say "UniqueChoice", and in our application based on the roles of "Admin" and "Showcase", we would like to have more/less options. What is the best way to accomplish this? Can it somehow be done through the GUI? Or will I need to override some files to add this functionality?

Comment: This is all possible, but you'll need to customize a template and implement the attributes and permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can assign a Role with ACL specific enough to show/hide individual attributes.

However, I think it would be possible by editing the renderer for the adminhtml catalog page.

***Note: This is not the Magento way of doing it.  This is just a proof of concept to show that it is possible to do.  This code works and hopefully it will inspire you to come up with a proper solution. ***

Edit the following file:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer.phtml`

Near the top of the file after `<?php $_element = $this->getElement() ?>`, add this code:

```
<?php

    // Admin Role that needs special permission
    $admin_role = "Showcase"; 

    // Array with all of the Attributes you want to exclude from your custom Admin Role
    $disallowed_attributes[]="name";
    $disallowed_attributes[]="description";
    $disallowed_attributes[]="short_description";
    // Keep adding these lines.  One for every attribute code that you want your special role to not show.

    $role = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleName();
    if (in_array($_element->getId(),$disallowed_attributes) && $role==$admin_role) {
        return false;  // Don't display this attribute
    }

?>
```

One thing to keep in mind is if you exclude an attribute that is a required field then you won't be able to save your product since that required field will not be showing.

I hope this helps get you started on creating a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, it can be done by overriding the template at following path

```
app/design/adminhtml/XXXX/backend/Magento_Catalog/templates/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml
```